# ScrollView's ContentView height is mismatching in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I created simple scrollview in storyboard with AutoLayout. It is working fine in iOS 10 and 11. But it is not working in iOS 9.

Step 1: I created simple view controller. In inside of that viewController it have default view. I added Another view(named as MainView) in inside of the superView and set top, bottom, leading and trailing as 0. And set background color as red.

Step 2: Then added ScrollView in inside of MainView and set top, bottom, leading and trailing as 0. And set background color as green.

Step 3: Now I added ContentView in inside of the scrollView and set top, bottom, leading and trailing as 0 & set equal width and height of MainView. And changed ContentView's height priority from 1000 to 250. And set background color as blue.

[image]

Now I embed the viewController with UINavigationController. It is perfectly working in iOS 10 and 11 like below mentioned image.

[image]

But it is not working in iOS 9.3 like below mentioned Image.

[image]

Issue is ContentView top has take NavigationBar height.

Please guide me what i did wrong.

Environment:

Xcode version: **9.2**

Swift version: **3.2**

macOS version running Xcode: **10.13.1**

Comment: What happens if you un-check `Adjust Scroll View Insets`?

Comment: @DonMag - Thanks for your solutions. It works perfectly.